# Изменение типа данных колонки в таблице

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица в базе данных, в данной таблице в одной из колонок время хранится в формате int.т.е хранится время в минутах как время в футбольном матче. допустим игрок забил гол на 90 минуте. следовательно в таблицу заносится 90. Мне нужно преобразовать данную колонку в формат time без потери данных. Как это сделать?

Comment: Не очень понятно в какой формат должно быть преобразовано.  В плане, время после чего?

Может быть Вам поможет данный ответ:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12568408/how-to-convert-an-integer-time-to-hhmmss00-in-sql-server-2008

Comment: Если без потери данных - то ОДНОЗНАЧНО создание нового поля, копирование в него данных, сотня проверок, и только после этого - удаление старого поля. Ещё лучше - перед началом процесса сделать бэкап таблицы.

Comment: поле time подразумевает часы, минуты, если говорить о правильном преобразовании, то наверно надо взять время начала матча и к этому значению добавить кол-во минут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create table #t(id int);
insert into #t values(1),(90),(45);
------
alter table #t alter column id varchar(5);
update #t set id= dateadd(minute,cast(id as int),cast('00:00:00' as time));
alter table #t alter column id time;
select * from #t;
drop table #t;
```